# powershell check the file is created today and not 0kb

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a logic where if the file created today & not 0kb in size following on from executing java -jar command then display backup has been successful and it moves on to moving files to new location. If not successful then I would like to carry out another attempt to backup file with a message that it was not successful and attempting backup again.. before it fails again and display message Backup Unsuccessful. I know my below code is not complete but unable to map out condition hence asking for your expert guidance.

```
# Directly invoking Bitbucket backup 
# #java -jar gerrit-2.15.4.war init –-batch -–no-auto-start -d gerrit_slave

cd C:\Atlassian\bitbucket-backup-client-4.0.0
Write-host "Path is set to cd C:\Atlassian\bitbucket-backup-client-4.0.0"
Write-host "Bitbucket backup is initiating....."
java -jar bitbucket-backup-client.jar
$File_check = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Atlassian\bitbucket-backup-client-4.0.0\backups\ | where 
{([datetime]::now.Date -eq $_.lastwritetime.Date)};

write-host $File_check

if ($file_exists.count -gt 0)
 {
  Write-host "Bitbucket Backup has finished with success!" -ForegroundColor Green
  Write-host "====================================== "
 }
Else {
     Write-host "Bitbucket Backup wasn't successful!" -ForegroundColor red
     Write-host "Trying Bitbucket Backup again !" -ForegroundColor red
      # how to call the backup process again?
     Write-host "====================================== "
    }
```

Comment: have changed the tags... to only powershell

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 things:

- A way to specify you're looking for files only
- Filtering out files that are 0 bytes in size

If you're using PowerShell 2.0, inspect the hidden `PsIsContainer` property to test that a given file system item is not a container/folder, then inspect the `Length` property for the file size:

```
Get-ChildItem ... |Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq [datetime]::Now.Date -and $_.Length -gt 0 }
```

If you're using PowerShell 3.0 or newer, you can place the `-File` parameter switch when calling `Get-ChildItem` against the filesystem provider to get only files:

```
Get-ChildItem ... -File |Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq [datetime]::Now.Date -and $_.Length -gt 0 }
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. I am using the suggestion but when i use it with if (test-path $file_check) it gives me false. Also not sure how do i initiate the backup again if truely hasn't created the file in the first instance.

Comment: Have tried this logic and it does return the file... but it tells me that it is FALSE
$File_check = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Atlassian\bitbucket-backup-client-4.0.0\backups\ | where {([datetime]::now.Date -eq $_.lastwritetime.Date) -and $_.Length -gt 0 };
$file_exists = Test-path $File_check
write-host $File_check "&" $($File_check.Length/1MB)
if ($file_exists -eq $true)
{ Write-host "Bitbucket Backup has finished with success!" -ForegroundColor Green }
Else {Write-host "Bitbucket Backup couldn't be done!" -ForegroundColor red}  
can't understand why it returns False although fileisthere

Comment: Have managed to find the workaround in order to check the file is there and used .count -gt 0 in the IF condition... like this ...if ($file_exists.count -gt 0). However need to find a way to call the backup gain which initially I carried out.

Answer (score 0):

Have managed to find the workaround in order to check the file is there and used .count -gt 0 in the IF condition... like this ...if ($file_exists.count -gt 0)